Efficiently Updating Matrix Multiplication Result When One Matrix Changes
Suppose you have two matrices $A \in Z_q^{m\times l}$ and $B \in Z_q^{l\times n}$, and the product $A\cdot B$ has already been computed. Now, matrix $B$ remains unchanged, but a few elements in matrix $A$ are modified (like updating some values, adding a new row, or deleting a specific row), resulting in a new matrix $A'$. How can we efficiently compute the updated product $A'B$ without recalculating the entire matrix product from scratch?
A possible way for updating the matrix is calculating $E = A'-A$ and computing $E \cdot B$ using sparse matrix - dense matrix multiplication algorithms, so what is the best way to calculate sparse matrix - dense matrix multiplications?

Comes from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/481504/efficiently-updating-matrix-multiplication-result-when-one-matrix-changes

Suppose $E=A'-A\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times l}_q$ has only a few non-zero rows (e.g. adding/removing a few rows to $A$), then you only need to compute the products of those rows with $B\in\mathbb{Z}^{l\times n}_q$. For simplicity assume that they are the first $r$ rows $E^1, \ldots, E^r$, then:
$$EB =\begin{bmatrix}-E^1- \\ \vdots \\-E^r- \\ 0_{(m-r)\times l}\end{bmatrix} B = \begin{bmatrix}-E^1B- \\ \vdots \\ -E^rB- \\ 0_{(m-r)\times n}\end{bmatrix}$$
This requires $O(r\cdot l \cdot n)$ instead of $O(m\cdot l \cdot n)$ operations.
Vice versa, assume that only a few columns are modified, then again wlog those can be the first $c$ columns $E_1, \ldots, E_c$ and:
$$EB =\begin{bmatrix} | & & | & | \\ E_1 & \ldots & E_c & 0_{m\times (l-c)} \\
| & & | & |\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} -B^1- \\ \vdots \\ -B^c- \\ -B^{c+1}- \\ \vdots \\ -B^l- \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{k=1}^c E_kB^k.$$
This is $O(m\cdot c \cdot n)$ instead of $O(m\cdot l \cdot n)$.
You can have a combination of both, where wlog the upper left $r \times c$ block of $E$ is non-zero. Then you can reduce the work to $O(r\cdot c \cdot n)$.
Of course, in practice the rows/columns don't have to be in the first indices. Then you may use a variant of a compressed sparse row or column matrix depending on what you know about how $E$ would look like.
Another option is that $B$ has rank $c$ and a known SVD $B = USV^T$. Then if $E$ is of rank $r$ and has a known SVD $E=QDU^T$, you can compute:
$$EB = QDU^TUSV^T = QDSV^T$$
If the singular values are ordered from greatest to least, then the last $(m-\min(c,r))$ rows of $DSV^T$ are zero. Suppose you know how to compute $y=Qx$ in $O(m\log k)$ time through some fast transform, where only the first $k=\min(c,r)$ elements of $x$ are non-zero. Then you can compute $EB = QDSV^T$ in $O(k + k\cdot n + m\cdot \log k \cdot n)$. This can be useful since $\log k$ could be much smaller than $l$. Even if you dpn't have a fast transform, if you know the columns $Q_j$ of $Q$ and the columns $V_j$ of $V$ then $$QDSV^T= \sum_{j=1}^k Q_j (D^j_jS^j_j)V_j^T,$$
and the time is $O(m\cdot k \cdot n)$.
Note that in practice the constants in the rutime scaling matter however. I just wrote $O(\cdot)$ as not to write arbitrary constants. Another point is that you are typically memory bound in such computations, so if you can procedurally compute the coefficients of $Q$ and $V$ (e.g. DTT or DWT transforms) instead of reading them from memory that could be a huge speed up.

Note that one of the updates, deleting a row of $A$, affects the product $AB$ in an especially simple way: delete the corresponding row of the product.  (This changes the shape of the matrix $A$ and the product $AB$, which might not be what the OP means.)  Similarly for adding a new row (insert new product row in the respecting place).

@hardmath I took adding/removing columns/rows to mean adding them/subtracting them from the corresponding row/column and not changing the matrix. But you may be right and they could have meant physically deleting those. Unrelated, but I am not sure what the relevance is of the matrix entries being from $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Granted some elements may zero out under addition/multiplication if they become multiples of $q$, but I don't think one can expect that this happens over a whole row/column in general. I guess there could be issues with the SVD idea over finite fields though.
